# What does it mean "up to much"?

Tags: british-english

A British guy ask me on fb

> Up to much?

How should I respond to it?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This kind of question doesn't seem to belong here. If you could edit your question by including context, it might be commented/answered.

Comment: The question "Up to much?" may be a truncated form of the question "Have you been up to much?"—which itself seems to be based on the idiomatic expression "I haven't been up to much," meaning "I haven't been particularly busy recently" or "I haven't done anything particularly interesting or important recently." Thus, the guy on Facebook may simply be asking you whether you have been doing anything interesting or important or time-consuming since you last communicated with him. You can be as loquacious or taciturn as you like in response.

Comment: Yeah, this is really a casual generic greeting ("Have you been up to much", when elided words are reinserted).  The usual response (at least 9 times out of 10) is something like "Not much, you?"  But you may, if you wish, reply with a brief mention of some interesting recent event in your life (like "Oh, I played a little golf this weekend"), or you may take is as an opportunity to begin a conversation on a relatively unrelated topic.  And it's always courteous to somehow reciprocate the question, if only with the "Not much, you?" response as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Sven Yargs , "Up to much?" is most likely to a truncated version of the question "Have you been up to much?" or simply, "Have you been doing much?"

And by mentioning that this is on Facebook and it is asked towards you, I can say that this question is most likely directed towards you.

> How do I respond to it?

Something like "Yeah, [mention something that you've done that is notable (consider how long it's been since you last talked)]..."

For example, "Sure have. I went skydiving yesterday - awesome! What about yourself?"